# How to save and load flows that receive by http request in Node red

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm new to node red. I am trying to custom node red. By default, node red will save and retrieve flows from the default directory ./node-red. Here I want to ask, when I saving flows, node-red will send the file flows.json to another server via https protocol and when accessing the node-red page will automatically get that flows.json file from the server to display to users. I have found where I can code to send file flows.json to server. But I don't know where should I put receive flows.json code  in source Node red

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a custom storage plugin for Node-RED that does the work to get and set the flows from your http endpoint.

https://nodered.org/docs/api/storage/

Comment: I am quite new at this, can you provide more details about the code?